# Absolute convergence implies convergence.

Tags: convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, absolute-convergence

1. Here (https://mathcs.org/analysis/reals/numser/proofs/absconv.html)  we read that absolute convergence implies convergence. I understant the proof and I am glad. Also there is an example which shows that converse is not true in general.

Okey.

2. In this (http://www.math.usm.edu/lee/mat771/hw3sol.pdf) paper on page 5, section 5 we read that in normed space convergence implies absolute convergence. ?!!!.

Question 1. About what space did we talk in 1?

Question 2. In the text bellow (from second link) we see that in normed space convergence implies absolut convergence.

[image]

But in the first link there is example when convergent sequence does not implies absolute convergence.

[image]

How to understand it? In this example we talk about R. And it is complate.

EDIT: Question 3. In wikipedia there is written that for absolute convergence we need norm. So we talk about absolute convergence only in the norm space. How to link this and the example above where we see that convergence does not implies absolute convergence?

Comment: convergence does not imply absolute convergence. Absolute convergence implies convergence for all sequences if and only if the space is complete (eg in $\Bbb{R}$)

Comment: The proof in the first link seems to work in any normed space (we just need an addition and the triangle inequality). I don't know what the sentence you indicated could mean in the second link. ($\Bbb R$ is a normed space, for example!)

Comment: @GregMartin No, completeness is needed. Consider a sum of positive rationals converging to an irrational...

Comment: @GregMartin Or if $X$ is any Banach space and $Y$ is a dense subspace there are absolutely convergent sums in $Y$ that do not converge (in $Y$).

Comment: So in the first link we talk about R space which is complate. And writter did not write it because this course was about R space. It was assumed by default. Yes?

Comment: @commenters Really?? What is the definition of absolute convergence in a normed space?

Comment: @GregMartin By definition a sequence convergence in normed space if ||x_n-x||\le \varepsilon \;\forall n \gt N. And this limit must be the element of this space. What is the conclusion ? Normed space must be complate?

Comment: @GregMartin This conclusion is false. So what is the intention of your question?